# Get nodes in shortestpath using py2neo

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

I am currently using `py2neo` to use a query using the shortest path, the `neo4j` code is:

```
MATCH p=(c:Ciudad)-[*]-(l:Ciudad) 
WHERE c.nombre = '%s' and l.nombre = '%s' 
RETURN p as shortestPath, reduce(precio=0, r in relationships(p) | precio+r.precio) AS totalPrecio 
ORDER BY totalPrecio ASC LIMIT 1;
```

When I use this on the web it gives me the list of Node 1 - Relation - Node 2, but when I execute this using:

```
string= "MATCH p=(c:Ciudad)-[*]-(l:Ciudad) 
WHERE c.nombre = '%s' and l.nombre = '%s' 
RETURN p as shortestPath, reduce(precio=0, r in relationships(p) | precio+r.precio) AS totalPrecio 
ORDER BY totalPrecio ASC LIMIT 1;" %(salida, llegada)

n = graph.run(string)
```

`shortestPath` only has the relationships and not the nodes.

Anyone knows how to get the same results as in the web?

Comment: Since your Cypher code is not using the [shortestPath()](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/match/#query-shortest-path) function, it is not producing what is guaranteed to be a single "shortest path" as the `shortestpath` value. It is just producing ALL matching paths of any length. Is that what you intended?

Answer (score 2):

*Aside: Your Cypher code is not actually producing what is guaranteed to be a single "shortest path" as the value for `shortestpath`. It is just producing ALL matching paths of any length. For the purposes of answering your question, I will ignore this issue and assume the existing behavior is what you want.*

If your results do not contain the nodes in the returned paths, you can just use the [NODES()](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/functions/list/#functions-nodes) function on the path, like in this snippet:

```
...
RETURN p as shortestPath, NODES(p) AS nodes, ...
```